# How to chop website name from url?

Tags: php

I would like to get website name from url

for example

- from `http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/` i want to get bbc
- from `http://security.blogs.cnn.com/2011/11/20/greatest-challenges-to-fighting-terror/?hpt=hp_t1` i want to get  cnn.com

I did write a code like this but doesn't seem to work in different circumstances

```
$name = substr($url, strpos($url, '/') +2 , strpos($url, '.')-3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use parse-url instead:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Alternatively look at the [PEAR NET_URL class](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL)

```
$name = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)
```

Comment: That will also get him the subdomain and topdomain. But i agree, it will be easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the programming language specifics, can you tell us what the catch-all rule is, in plain English? Why does cnn.com retain its last ".com" while bbc.co.uk becomes just "bbc"? What's the general rule?